# Does shaking a water bottle increase the temperature of the water inside?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, temperature, everyday-life

If I am at a cold place, can I warm a bottle of water just by continuously shaking it?

If yes, how long would it approximately take, i.e., is it physically possible or just theoretically?

Comment: The last post addresses your question: https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/2zekje/is_it_possible_to_boil_water_by_shaking_agitating/

Comment: The answer is yes.  Viscous deformation of the water causes its internal energy and temperature to increase.  The answer to your second question is that it will start to warm ever so slightly as soon as you start shaking it.

Comment: Are you shaking it with a robot arm?  Just touching it will "heat it" since you are hotter than the water (assuming the bottle is in equilibrium with the cold place).  How hot do you want the water to be?

Comment: @Chester Miller Thanks. Since you mentioned viscous deformation, would there be a difference to this situation if the bottle(i am assumimg it to be a cylinder) was spining about the axis that joins the centers of the opp. faces.

Comment: @ggcg No, i was assuming that the my body doesn't give the container any heat. Its very nicely insulated so that whatever heat is produced inside doesn't get lost to the cold environment. About the temperature of the water, umm. i guess 60-70℃..  i mean how hot would you consider good enough to drink in a cold place?

Comment: In order for viscous deformation to contribute to the thermal balance on the fluid, the fluid has to actually be *deforming.*  This won't happen if the fluid is rotating as a rigid body.

Comment: @Chester Miller i though as much. Thanks

Comment: https://what-if.xkcd.com/71/

Answer (score 16):

Let us assume you shake from each side at a rate $f$ of say four times per second attaining $\Delta v/2=5\ \mathrm{mph}$ $\simeq$ [8](https://www.google.com/search?nord=1&safe=off&source=hp&filter=0&q=5miles%20in%20km) kph before reversing directions, and that some fraction of the energy $\beta$ you give each switch is converted into heat which is absorbed by the water, and that none of it is radiated out.

The value of $\beta$ will change based on how full the bottle is.  If the bottle is 100% full, then there will be no internal motions for viscosity to convert the energy into heat, and $\beta\simeq0$.

To understand this situation (the $\beta\simeq0$ full-bottle case), one could "heat" the water by putting the bottle into a simple harmonic oscillator (with a spring), and it would go back and forth without heating the water and without any expenditure of energy.   By conservation of energy, no heat can be added to the water.

Continuing, the desired change in energy is

$$\Delta E=M_\text{water}C_V\Delta T,$$

where $M_\text{water}$ is the mass of the water, $C_V$ is the heat capacity of water, and $T$ is the temperature, with $\Delta$ denoting changes.

Meanwhile, the total heat supplied will be

$$\Delta E=N \beta {1 \over 2}M_\text{water}{\Delta v}^2,$$

where $N$ is the number of single-direction shakes.

Solving for $N$, we get

$$N={2C_V\Delta T \over {\beta \Delta v}^2}.$$

The total time it takes will be

$$T={N\over f}={2C_V\Delta T \over \beta f{\Delta v}^2}.$$

If warm is $100\ \mathrm{^\circ F}\simeq38\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$ and cold is $32\ \mathrm{^\circ F}=0\mathrm{^\circ C} $, $\Delta T\simeq68\ \mathrm{^\circ F}\simeq38\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$. 5 mph $\simeq$ [2.2](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&nord=1&ei=vP4sW9TlDoiE5wKc2KjYDA&q=5%20miles%20per%20hour%20in%20meters%20per%20second&oq=5%20miles%20per%20hour%20in%20meters%20per%20second&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i8i30k1.3646.3876.0.4724.2.2.0.0.0.0.95.179.2.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.179...0i7i30k1j0i8i7i30k1.0.DwQgRtg0DQQ) m/s. So, if $\beta=0.5$,

$$T={2\times 4184\ \mathrm{\frac{J}{kg\ K}} 38\ \mathrm K \over 0.5 \times 4\ \mathrm s^{-1} \times \left(2\times2.2\ \mathrm{m\over s}\right)^2}=8212\rm \space seconds\simeq 2 \space hours \space 16 \space minutes.$$

This doesn't account for radiative losses during that time, although that won't become too important unless you want to make tea.  Actually, if you wanted boiling hot water for that purpose, then you could have made such tea in a few minutes of shaking (without changing the temperature much) because the motion will drastically increase the effective diffusion rate of liquid through the tea leaves vs. stagnant water.

I'd like to thank Loong for syntax corrections and also Ujjwal Barman for asking a question that made me want to include a $\beta$ factor, as the original answer had none and I'd hate to have someone shake a full bottle for hours only to find disappointment!

Comment: if i am correct, you've considered that at those moments where i reverse the direction of motion of the bottle the kinetic energy of the water molecules inside all get converted to heat. but for that to be true they'll have to come to rest. I dont think thats what will happen. imagining a simple situation, if a single ball collides with a wall, only time its KE is converted wholly into heat is when it sticks to the wall, not when it bounces back. if you see what i am getting at..

Comment: You are largely correct.  I've added a factor of beta to account for the elastic nature of accelerating the water and gave you credit for the idea.  Sorry for the delays as there was a power outage in the middle of me editing and I'm still learning how this site works.

Comment: I think the important question is what proportion of shaking energy goes to the internal energy of the water? First, I'd argue the water is nearly frictionless, and mostly elastic collisions, meaning very little of the energy actually converts to heat. Second, most of the energy goes into changing direction of the vessel--not actually changing the internal energy of the water, when you shake it +x, you then shake it -x.

Comment: James, you're arguing for a low $\beta$ without saying so.  For simplicity, I used 0.5, but I agree it could be lower.  What value do you think is better?

Comment: Turbulence is an efficient energy sink.  Given how well a water bottle (doesn't) bounce, 0.5 seems very conservative.

Comment: BowlOfRed, I am not sure this kid would agree.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TVjse3ENC7E

Comment: Great answer. May I ask you to include conversions of all values to SI units? So that I (and very likely many others) can get a better idea of what values you're talking about :) If you do that I'll upvote, thanks :)

Comment: @Jason i agree. the value of β should be much lower. For one, if it wasn't, the consequences wouldn't be so subtle and two, the velocity of the water molecules just before and after it collides with the end of the bottle seems to look  very much alike.Thanks to all of you for all the valuable replies.

Comment: @JasonArthurTaylor i just watched that youtube video.  physics hurts, but i'm still alive.

Comment: Dear Hamsterrific, per your request I've converted miles per hour to kph and deg F to deg C.  But, I didn't see anything else to convert.  Was that it? (My goodness I do feel like such a prostitute...)

Comment: "the velocity of the water molecules just before and after it collides with the end of the bottle seems to look very much alike" U.B. You really want me to answer a question about how heat is created when an object is dropped on a floor.  I am not sure there are enough characters here.  Perhaps ask it as a separate question?  In short, velocities get converted from 1d to 3d and you get a square root added to the thermal motions.  Indeed, the q can be answered using just velocity analysis.  I originally was going to do that as a separate submission for kicks but this is a fluid so it is tricky.

Comment: @Jason Arthur Taylor i never said heat wasnt produced in a collision (if that is what you thought i meant). All i was trying to say was that if the object lost more velocity after the collision, it would mean that its kinetic energy must have been converted to some other form i.e heat, sound, etc. so amount of heat produced should depend on the objects velocity after collision. But i do realize now that maybe its not so simple here since we are talking about a fluid. Thanks.

Comment: It is complex.  I haven't worked it all out, but where the energy goes should depend upon the acceleration of the water, the bulk modulus (2.2 GPa), hardness of the plastic bottle, etc.  I think a lot would go into the shaker's muscles, as I pointed out in my comment on the other answer, which IMO is wrong.

Answer (score 9):

A bottle closed at one end with a bung at the other end has some water in it.

The bung has a thermometer passing through it to measure the temperature of the water.

The bottle, initially in a vertical position, is repeatedly inverted.

With no heat losses you can equate the loss in gravitational potential energy to the gain in heat energy.

$$mg\Delta h N= mC\Delta \theta$$

where $m$ is the mass of a small amount of water in the bottle of length $\Delta h$ which is inverted $N$ times, $g$ is the gravitational field strength, $C$ the specific heat capacity of water and $\Delta \theta$ the temperature rise.

$$\Rightarrow \Delta \theta = \dfrac{9.8 \times 0.3}{4200} N= 0.0007 \, N$$

for a bottle of length $0.3\,\rm m $

So about $1400$ inversions should raise the temperature by $1\, ^\circ \rm C$.

Heat loss and the thermal capacity of the bottle will mean that many more inversions will be necessary.
Also one must  insulate the bottle so that the process of inversion using hands does not heat the water.

So let it be $3\times 1400 = 4200 $ inversions.

One inversion every second gives a time of about $70$ minutes to gain $1\, ^\circ \rm C$ so perhaps it should be a $0.2\, ^\circ \rm C$ temperature rise and a more reasonable time of approximately $15$ minutes.

---

**Update** after doing two experiments

[image]

The first experiment I tried was to use lead shot in a tube of length $0.77 \,\rm m$ with some lead shot in it.
I measured the initial temperature of the lead shot $(24.3 \rm ^\circ C)$ and the final temperature after $100$ inversions $(25.2 \rm ^\circ C)$.
Assuming no heat losses, 100% conversion of gravitational potential energy into heat etc this gives an unexpected specific heat capacity of lead of about $800\, \rm J\,kg^{-1}\,K^{-1}$.
Unexpected because the documented value for the specific heat capacity of lead is $160\, \rm J\,kg^{-1}\,K^{-1}$ but also because [a report found by @JasonArthurTaylor](http://www.physics.uwo.ca/~psimpson/example_report.pdf) using the same method found the specific heat capacity of lead to be approximately $800\, \rm J\,kg^{-1}\,K^{-1}$.
This seems to indicate that although the method does show an increase in temperature the temperature rise is well below the value predicted using a simple theory.

Although the result of the first experiment was unexpected I did not have time to repeat it because I wanted to address the question posed by the OP regarding a bottle of water.

To a $2$ litre plastic bottle was added about $200\,\rm cm^3$ of water and a thermometer with $0.1^\circ\rm C$ graduations was used to measure the temperature of the water at one minute intervals.
The bottle was shaken at a rate of approximately $170$ shakes per minute over a distance of about $15\,\rm cm$
All I wanted to find out is the order of magnitude of the temperature rise.

The water temperature before the shaking started was $23.8 ^\circ \rm C$ and the water temperature at one minute intervals up to $5$ minutes was $24.0 ^\circ \rm C$,  $24.4 ^\circ \rm C$, $24.6 ^\circ \rm C$,  $24.9^\circ \rm C$ and  $25.1 ^\circ \rm C$.

So this is good evidence that shaking a water bottle does increase the temperature of the water inside the bottle.

Comment: "With no heat losses you can equate the loss in gravitational potential energy to the gain in heat energy."

I question this.  If generally true, would not this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1feybxNChU0 slow down in 1 revolution if tilted at 90$^\circ$?

Comment: @JasonArthurTaylor I have suggested that the is “some (a little) water” in the bottle so the water falls the length of the bottle. In the video the jars are (almost) full of water. What I have described is the basis of a Physics demonstration using lead shot. http://www.physics.usyd.edu.au/super/therm/tpteacher/demos/shottube.html The problem with having a container nearly full of water is making the water move.

Comment: But your word $some$ does not actually exclude $full$, as you imply.  Lead is unusual, and was selected for a reason.  It depends upon how rapidly the collisions occur in relation to the break up self acceleration limit.  If it is too low, there won't be the energy conversion.

Comment: @JasonArthurTaylor If you read further on I use the phrase “small amount of water”.

Comment: Was not your sole rationale for your use of this word regarding the approximation of ignoring the height of the water as compared to $\Delta h$, the height of the bottle?  I'd guess *yes* because your use of "small" would have probably accompanied "some" instead of $\Delta h$.  Now, you are implying that you already knew of the lack of turbulence issue that I had already pointed out in my answer, but the location of "small" in your answer IMO does not support this position.

Comment: @JasonArthurTaylor Mine was an attempt at an order of magnitude calculation so what was important was important was a reasonable approximation for the height through which the water fell. In my method the water hits the bottom and settles down before the bottle is turned upside down again so where else can the loss of potential energy go other than to be converted into heat? Allegedly on his honeymoon Joule did a similar experiment by measuring the temperature of the water at the top and bottom of a waterfall.

Comment: In using "the only remaining possible answer is" logic, you have to consider all possible effects.  I think you are arrogant. "Where else...?"  Into deltoid and other muscles.  If it helps you, consider if I were to throw you a baseball, and you were to catch it.  Does all the ball kinetic energy goes into heating the baseball?  Please skim and comment on the last part of http://www.physics.uwo.ca/~psimpson/example_report.pdf . "The specific heat of lead was found to be 833 J/kg K. The theoretical value is 157 [J/kg K]."  Read also the last line in your url asking why hard copper was not used.

Comment: @JasonArthurTaylor The reason for using lead rather than copper or indeed water is that it has a lower specific heat capacity and so all other things being equal will give a higher temperature rise. As to the experiment mentioned in your last comment I think that is was not well done and the conclusions are not very convincing.

Comment: The certainty of your first sentence exemplifies my points.  See this table for a more important unique benefit of lead  http://www.kayelaby.npl.co.uk/general_physics/2_2/2_2_2.html  .  It was the first one I discovered on google.  Please, give me some data you like better so we have more than 1 data point.

Comment: Interesting.  When you did the experiment with lead shot, you are saying you got the same result I found on a google search.  This goes to confirm that the idea that all the energy goes into heat is wrong, correct?

Comment: @JasonArthurTaylor Not necessarily as it could be heating the base which the lead shot heats. I did not have time to do any more experimenting but as the diameter of the lead shot was quite large the thermal contact between the shot and the thermometer was not very good. So the final temperature reading might well have been too low?

Comment: I don't think the plastic is heated.  My theory above of what happens is that the energy is going back into your arm muscles.  It is like when you are in the gym and lowering the weight during the eccentric phase of a rep.  For the energy to get converted into heat, the lead needs to deform, not merely press against, the plastic, during the collisions/flips. To get a better transfer, the ends of the plastic would perhaps need a harder and stronger covering (than thin lead), like thick steel.   I upvoted your answer since the data will be useful to others teaching this.

Comment: @JasonArthurTaylor With that comment in mind the lead shot the tube was placed on the bench as it was rotated into the vertical position. I am fairly sure that the plastic ends would deform. Perhaps a search of the Internet might reveal more experimental results?